# Multy Media picker, razor syntax newbie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

i have used stackoverflow for a long time to do research bit this time i have a question of my own.
I am using umbraco and the razor syntax for the first time.
The idea is that i have a Repeatable text string property and a Multi Media picker and i am trying to display them in 3 columns with the first item from each multiple and repeatable in the 1st column etc...
 Here is what i have so far:

```
<!-- MAIN SECTION -->
<section class="main">
    <div class="wrap row small-up-1  medium-up-3 large-up-3">
        @{
        var something = new object();
        var dynamicMediaItem= Umbraco.Media(something);
        }
        @if (CurrentPage.HasValue("icons"))
        {
        foreach (var icon in CurrentPage.icons.Split(','))
        {
        dynamicMediaItem = Umbraco.Media(icon);
        }
        }
        @if (CurrentPage.repeatableText.Length > 0)
        {
        foreach (var line in CurrentPage.repeatableText)
        {
        <div class="columns column-block">
            <img src="@dynamicMediaItem.umbracoFile" />
            <h2>About Me</h2>
            <p>@line</p>
            <a href="AboutMe.html" class="button large expanded">Learn more</a>
        </div>
        }
        }
    </div>
</section>
```